# Symfony 6.2 app not working as soon as a Command name is defined

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/html/
```

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        root /var/www/html/public;
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

I installed Symfony Console `"symfony/console": "^6.2"`.

composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "symfony/runtime": "^6.2",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^6.2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^6.2",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^6.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "symfony/console": "^6.2"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "symfony/runtime": true
    }
  }
}
```

I added a src/cli.php

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();

$application->add(new \App\Commands\ExtractAuthorPortraitsCommand());
$application->run();
```

I added a command

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Commands;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ExtractAuthorPortraitsCommand extends Command
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

As soon as I add a name to the command

```
#[AsCommand(name: 'app:extract-author-portraits')]
class ExtractAuthorPortraitsCommand extends Command
```

a request to the Symfony app (http://localhost:8084) then gives me an empty response.

And the PHP log shows Console Tool stuff which does not come in the log when Command has no name.

```
Console Tool
Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]
Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
Available commands:
  completion                    Dump the shell completion script
  help                          Display help for a command
  list                          List commands
 app
  app:extract-author-portraits  
172.21.0.3 -  18/Jan/2023:07:28:25 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Really weird to be honest. First, why is "symfony/console" inside require-dev instead of require ? Since it's inside require-dev, is your env properly set in dev mode ?

Comment: @ThomasLaveau The Command is only used temporarily during development for a one-time operation before going productive. The `.env` file contains `APP_ENV=DEV`, and I removed the entire var/cache folder manually, so I would say the environment is set properly dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

//Registering the Command
//In PHP 8 and newer versions, you can register the command by adding the AsCommand //attribute to it. example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use App\Services\ContactService;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

// the "name" and "description" arguments of AsCommand replace the
// static $defaultName and $defaultDescription properties
#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:send-contact',
    description: 'send a new message from client',
    hidden: false,
    aliases: ['app:send-contact']
)]
class SendContactCommand extends Command
{
    private $contactRepository;
    private $mailer;
    private $ContactService;
    private $UserRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ContactRepository $contactRepository,
        MailerInterface $mailer,
        ContactService $contactService,
        UserRepository $userRepository
    ) {
        $this->contactRepository = $contactRepository;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->ContactService = $contactService;
        $this->UserRepository = $userRepository;
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
  
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output):int
    {   
        $nom = $this->UserRepository->getNom();
        $email = $this->UserRepository->getEmail();

        $toSend = $this->contactRepository->findBy(['isSent' => false]);
        $address = new Address($nom, $email);

        foreach ($toSend as $mail) {
            $email = (new Email())  ->from($mail->getEmail())
                                    ->to($address)
                                    ->subject('Nouveau message de '. $mail->getNom())
                                    ->text($mail->getMessage());

            $this->mailer->send($email);

            $this->ContactService->isSent($mail);
        }
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```